# Omitted "Because" in "Coming from Alaska, Claude was unaccustomed to Florida’s heat"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context

I think the original sentence is **Because he was coming from Alaska, Claude was unaccustomed to Florida’s heat.**

1. Why is **because** omitted? What is the name of this action? When do we do this?
   A good link on this is appreciated.
2. Does *coming from Alaska* implies he is from Alaska that is he was born in Alaska? Or it merely says he had been in Alaska before he came to Florida?
3. What is the name of the phrase *Coming...,* which is telling the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Coming from Alaska, Claude was unaccustomed to Florida's heat.

(Claude is a man's name).

To "come from" a place can mean that the place is one's homeland or home town, where one was born and raised, or where one has resided for quite a long time. To "come from a place" can also refer to one's most recent starting point on a trip. *I've just come from the airport.*

Here, it is most likely the former meaning, for if we wanted to say that Claude had gotten used to the cold after only a relatively brief stay in Alaska, we'd probably say so explicitly to avoid any ambiguity. *After spending the winter in Arizona, Claude found Florida's summer humidity oppressive.*

The clause is called the *protasis*.

Comment: Claude is both masculine and feminine, although the male name is much more common than the female name. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_(given_name)

Comment: Interesting. I've heard Claudette, but never Claude.

Comment: The only reason I knew is because I came across a mention of Claude de Bectoz, a French abbess and philosopher that corresponded with Francis I. One of my Francophile friends explained that it was a unisex name.

Comment: Probably not too many female Claudes in Alaska, though :-)

Comment: I don't think there are many female Claudes that aren't originally from France :) I wouldn't completely rule it out though. Didn't France claim part of Alaska at one point in history?

Comment: This sentence is not conditional, then would you tell me why you call that clause a protasis? link:http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/protasis

Comment: I used *protasis* more broadly to mean the introductory clause of a sentence. A conditional clause is one kind of introductory clause.  See OED, #3.

Answer (score 1):

Because she came from Alaska, Claude was unaccustomed to Florida's heat.

We use this type of sentences in spoken English. If we replace "because she came" with "coming", it becomes a present participle clause, which can be used to give a reason. This type of clause is used in written English, which serves as an adjective.

As for coming from Alaska, it means she was either born in Alaska or lived in Alaska.